# UITextField Frame from TableViewCell

Tags: ios, ipad

Why can't I get the correct frame for a tableViewCell textField?

myCustomCell has a leftDetailTF and a rightDetailTF textfield.

The log statement below generates the same rect coordinates no matter what cell/textfield I tap. LOG: Frame = {{470, 1}, {200, 24}}

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

myCustomCell *cell = (myCustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSLog(@"Frame = %@",NSStringFromCGRect(cell.rightDetailTF.frame));
```

Comment: call cellForRowAtIndexPath will rebulid cell or get a cached cell,So don't get what you want.you can record textField in a Array,and to call it in didselectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I need the rect for the rightDetailsTF. rectForRowAtIndexPath returns the rect for the cell not the textField that is in the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check the frame of the subviews with in the superview's superview you can use this.

```
  CGRect rect = [cell.rightDetailTF.superview convertRect:cell.rightDetailTF.frame toView:self.view];
NSLog(@"Rect:%@",NSStringFromCGRect(rect));
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the frame of the cell...

```
CGRect cellFrame = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Then get the frame of the right text field...

```
myCustomCell *cell = (myCustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
CGRect rightDetailTFFrame = cell.rightDetailTF.frame;
```

Then combine the two:

```
CGRect resultFrame = CGRectMake(cellFrame.origin.x + rightDetailTFFrame.origin.x, cellFrame.origin.y + rightDetailTFFrame.origin.y, rightDetailTFFrame.size.width, rightDetailTFFrame.size.height);
```

Comment: resultFrame origin.x is still incorrect. it looks like cell.rightDetailTF.origin.x is returning a point that is offset to the left by like 600.

Comment: are you doing custom layout in layoutSubviews of your cell?

Answer (score 0):

use Array to record rect.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)cell.......:IndexPath...
{
      CGRect rect = cell.rightDetailTF.cellFrame;
      NSMutableDictionary* dic = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init...:4];
      [dic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:rect.origin.x] forKey:...1];
      //... rect.origin.y,rect.size.with,rect.size.height
      [arr addObject:dic];
      [dic release];
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
      NSMutableDictionary* dic = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      CGRect rect = CGRectMake([dic objectForKey:...1],........);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the thing is, for a UITableView in iOS you the frame is fixed for all views in a cell. Therefore, you **CAN'T** modify these frames. Whatever frame you set for the cell, it will be restored when `[cell reloadData]` is called automatically.

Have you correctly initialized the views in the `init` method?

Just over-ride the "loadsubviews" method in your **"myCustomCell"** class.

Print out the CGRect for the sub-views in this method, if the frames are in-correct, you must have an issue when you are initializing the views in the init method.